# Density of Dynamical System in Function Space

Tags: real-analysis, dynamical-systems

Let $\mathcal{X}\subset C^0(\mathbb{R}^d;\mathbb{R}^d)$ be a non-empty, proper subset which is closed under composition.  Under what conditions is the set $\mathcal{X}^{\infty}$ defined by
$$
\mathcal{X}^{\infty}\triangleq \left\{
g \in C^0(\mathbb{R}^d;\mathbb{R}^d)
: (\exists f \in \mathcal{X})\, f= 
\underbrace{g\circ\dots\circ g}_{\mbox{n times composed}}
\right\}
,
$$
dense in $C^0(\mathbb{R}^d;\mathbb{R}^d)$?

**Extended Question - Topological Version**
If $\mathbb{R}^d$ is replaced by any complete metric space, what additional constraints do I need, in addition to the ones on $\mathcal{X}$?

Comment: I'm puzzled.  Where does Hilbert come in?

Comment: @herbsteinberg .... this is very embarrassing, but it was an accidentally posted title to an old question.  Thanks for pointing it out, its fixed now :)

Comment: What is the topology on $C^0(\mathbb R^d,\mathbb R^d)$

Comment: The supremum (metric) topology

Comment: So are we only considering continuous functions with compact support?

Comment: @K Power  It looks like all bounded continuous functions.

Comment: Yes, only continuous with compact support works